# findstr confused by colon?

Tags: batch-file, findstr

If I run from cmd.exe:

```
findstr "\"A\" : \"B\"" c:\temp\sample.json

echo %errorlevel%
```

with the contents of sample.json being

```
{
    "Abad" : "B"
}
```

errorlevel shows as 0.

If I replace ':' with '.', I again get 0. But, if I instead use two '.'s:

```
findstr "\"A\" ..\"B\"" c:\temp\sample.json
```

findstr correctly returns an errorlevel of 1. What is findstr trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTFM.

With a space between strings, FINDSTR looks for string1 **OR** string2 **OR** string3...

Your `FINDSTR` is thus looking for `"A"` **OR** `:` **OR** `"B"`

To look for a string containing spaces, use (eg)

```
 findstr /c:"\"A\" : \"B\""
```